# Eclipse EcLemma number of covered instructions more than lines of code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclemma

In the coverage result, it shows that I've covered 9 instructions while there are only 5 lines highlighted green. Which are the other 4 instructions?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it means bytecode instructions.

Comment: @shmosel : I don't think that's the case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the dropdown arrow at the top right of the Coverage box. It'll give you a [couple different ways to measure your coverage](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html). The default seems to be instructions (bytecode instructions), but you can manually select lines.

[image: 2]

The reason you are seeing 9 instructions is because there are 9 bytecode instructions in `Foo`:

```
$ javap -c Foo.class 
Compiled from "Foo.java"
public class Foo {
  public Foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #22                 // String Test
       5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: new           #1                  // class Foo
      11: invokespecial #30                 // Method "<init>":()V
      14: return
}
```

Comment: This is pure genius! Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 2):

As @schmosel says, it is counting bytecode instructions.

You can verify this by reading the EMMA [reference documentation](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference_single/reference.html) (EclEMMA is an Eclipse GUI wrapped around EMMA), in which the phrase "bytecode instructions" is used throughout.

Comment: Can you please refer me to a link where I can find the bytecode instructions EcLemma is running?

Comment: The most general solution is javap https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html -- you may seek out your own GUI equivalent if you like.

Comment: So which class should I run with the javap command for my query, if you may know?